# Error loading a 3.0 framework dll Unity

Tags: dll, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load a managed dll into my project. *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.ServiceModel.dll*

Its an Empty project. I paste this dll into my Asset/Plugin folder. I compile for Windows8 (Universal App)anyway it fails with all SO. I change API Compatibilty level to 2.0. It seems its load without problem. As soon as I play Unity the following mistake appears:

> SpritePacker failed to get types from System.ServiceModel,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx.
>   Error: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
>   UnityEditor.Sprites.Packer:GetSelectedPolicyId()

Somebody with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked out loading the dll from:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\gac\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089"

Other dlls where not valid. The reason why it is like this I do not know it.